# Opening a closed NSWindow in Swift crashes application

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nswindow

I have a Preferences window in a SwiftUI Mac app. The window is opened by clicking the "Preferences..." menu item. The window appears as it should upon the first opening. But the application will crash if the Preferences window is closed and then re-opened from the menu item. How do I properly close and re-open the Preferences window without crashing the app?

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
    var prefsWindow: NSWindow!

    @IBAction func openPrefsWindow(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {

        let prefsView = PreferencesView(

        prefsWindow = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable],
            backing: .buffered,
            defer: false)
        prefsWindow.center()
        prefsWindow.title = "Preferences"
        prefsWindow.setFrameAutosaveName("Preferences Window")
        prefsWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: prefsView)
        prefsWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let contentView = ContentView()

        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered,
            defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
}
```

**PreferencesView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct PreferencesView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Preferences Window")
            .frame(width: 400, height: 200)
    }
}

struct PreferencesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PreferencesView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It has nothing to do with SwiftUI. You have to set something for prefesWindow like this:

```
  .....
       prefsWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: prefsView)
       prefsWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
       prefsWindow.isReleasedWhenClosed = false

 }
```

See the last line above.